# Python regex ip

Tags: python, regex, validation, ip

I believe IP can only range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. I see lot's of complicated regex answers to match and validate IP addresses on stack overflow. Tell me what's wrong with mine.

```
ip = re.compile(r'[0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*\.[0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*\.[0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*\.[0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*\')
```

It works.

Comment: Try this regexp `'\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'`

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely understand why you used `[0-2]*[0-5]*[0-5]*`, and I believe I made a similar mistake once. The problem here is that it can only match 000-055, 100-155, 200-255. The code you need should be something like this:

```
(?:(?:[01]*[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))
```

For each three digit sequence.

In essence, you're telling the regex that the input should have either:

- any number from 0 to 199, given by `[01][0-9][0-9]`
- or any number from 200 to 249, given by `2[0-4][0-9]`
- or any number from 250 to 255, given by `25[0-5]`

Comment: ahh I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If the solution solved your problem completely, it'd be great if you could mark this answer as correct for future reference :)

Comment: I'm a newbie SO wont let me mark it correct. I'll come back to this :)